# Get object sent to function with this.value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the object itself when a function receives a value from it?

Example:

```
<input id="field1" onblur="testFunction(this.value)" />
<input id="field2" onblur="testFunction(this.value)" />

<script>
function testFunction(x){
  field_value_length = x.length;
  field_object = ????;
}
</script>
```

When I blur the field, I apply it's length to "field_value_length" in `testFunction()`. Ok!

Is there a way to get the **object** itself (the input) where data in "x" came from, so I can get other properties from the form field that has sent data value to the function, like the "id" etc. just like it was sending `testFunction(this)` instead `testFunction(this.value)`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The object that sent data to the function. One of the two inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is sent to the function is the value from the input... Only.

But nothing prevents you from sending the input element, using just `this`.

```
<input id="field1" onblur="testFunction(this)" />
<input id="field2" onblur="testFunction(this)" />

<script>
function testFunction(x){
  field_value_length = x.value.length;
  field_id = x.id;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So, sending the value to the function, it's not possible to identify where input it came from?

Comment: Not if you don't send the info.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.